# Import Table definition (fields) from excel sheet

Tags: sql-server, database, excel

My excel sheets contains my table definitions as follows:

```
FieldName         FieldType
Id                Int
Name              Text
```

Each Sheet represents a different table and I got about 20 tables with about a total of 800 fields.I need to be creating these tables in my database, in the quickest way possible. The only solutions I have in mind are:
1- Create them one by one manually
2- Copy and past the excel sheet field definitions into SQL management studio and add/adjust the necessary syntax for each field to do "Create Table" query.

I find both of these solutions time-consuming, Is there a way to directly import the table definition from an Excel Sheet?

Comment: Maybe do a SELECT INTO from each of the sheets?

Comment: you will need to resort to VBA scripting. Do some research, google *excel vba create sql table* and google *excel vba For Each ws In Worksheets*  then try some of the code results you might find, and come back with  more concrete questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to build table definitions in Excel.  Either through VB script/macro and/or Excel formulas.  VB Script would provide the opportunity for a more robust solution but could be more involved.  However, formulas can get most of the job done quickly.

I put an example together with formulas.  In your question, you present field name and field type.  It would be helpful to add field width and precision for variable length string fields and numeric fields.  You also mentioned that you are using SQL Server.  In that case, I would use actual SQL Server field types in the spreadsheet.  For example, use "VARCHAR" instead of "TEXT".  The following is an example:

```
 |A          |B        |C         |D        |E                          |F
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1|FieldName  |FieldType|FieldWidth|Precision|                           |
2|           |         |          |         |CREATE TABLE table1 (      |Typed Text
3|Id         |Int      |          |         |Id Int ,                   |Formula
4|Name       |Varchar  |30        |         |Name Varchar( 30 ),        |Formula
5|DateOfBirth|Date     |          |         |DateOfBirth Date ,         |Formula
6|HoursWorked|Numeric  |5         |2        |HoursWorked Numeric( 5, 2),|Formula
7|           |         |          |         |)                          |Typed Text
8|           |         |          |         |go                         |Typed Text
```

[Snapshot of table creation Excel worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp0JX.jpg)

In the example, Column E rows 2 through 8 contain the resulting SQL script.  Further, Column E, Row 2 is simply typed straight in as text.  The same is the case for Column E Row 7 and Row 8.

For Column E Rows 3 through 6 there is a formula entered.

The formula that would be in Column E Row 3 is as follows:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D3),TRIM(CONCATENATE(A3," ",B3,"( ",C3,", ",D3,"),")),IF(ISNUMBER(C3),TRIM(CONCATENATE(A3," ",B3,"( ",C3," ",D3,"),")),TRIM(CONCATENATE(A3," ",B3," ",C3," ",D3,","))))
```

That formula, once pasted into Column E Row 3 could be copied down through Row 6.

The results in Column E rows 2 through 8 can then be copied and pasted into SQL Server Management Studio to create table1.

Note: Once script is in Management Studio, remove the "," in the last field definition.  It's only there because the Excel formula is not robust enough to keep it from showing up.